# Find integer solutions to$\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{z}+\frac{z}{x}=3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have been looking at [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/249377/proving-that-an-equation-has-no-natural-solutions) that has no positive integer solutions, and I became curious regarding the similar following problem:

I am trying to find solutions to$\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}=3$, where $a,b,c \in \mathbb{N}$.

It is fairly clear that $a=b=c=1$ is a solutions, and thus, $a=b=c=d\in \mathbb{N}$ is a family of solutions where each variable is the same. (Not terribly interesting). I am curious if there are other solutions and how to find them. If not, how could one prove there exist none?

Comment: Hint: AM $\ge$ GM and what are the conditions for AM $=$ GM?

Comment: This well-know application of AM-GM has been proved here *many* times, e.g. see the linked dupe (and its links).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AM-GM gives

$$\frac{\frac{x}{y} + \frac{y}{z} + \frac{z}{x}}{3}\geq\sqrt[3]{\frac{x}{y}\cdot\frac{y}{z}\cdot\frac{z}{x}} = 1$$

Where equality is achieved when $\frac{x}{y} = \frac{y}{z} = \frac{z}{x}$. This gives $x = \frac{y^2}{z}$, and substituting gives $y^3 = z^3$ i.e. $y = z$. Therefore, the only solutions are $x = y = z = k$ where $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Hey, it's Gareth again!

Comment: @ClydeKertzer Hey, do you know me/do I know you? hahaha

Comment: You helped on my question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4436298/find-all-primes-a-b-c-such-that-a2a-b2b-c2c-form-an-arithm

Comment: Ah, the arithmetic progression one. Nice

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).